# I would like to implement a `split function/template` which takes as input a string and a delimiter and returns a split array of the string

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-1.0

I would like to implement a `split function/template` in XSLT which takes as input a string and a delimiter and returns a split array of the string..

Or rather I'd like the ability to do something along the lines of:

```
<xsl:call-template name="F">
    <xsl:with-param name="input" select="'a,b,c,d,e'"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="replacement">
    <option value='$x'>$x</option>
</xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>
```

which will give me

```
<option value='a'>a</option><option value='b'>b</option><option value='c'>c</option><option value='d'>d</option><option value='e'>e</option>
```

Question targeted at XSLT 1.0 (but i don't mind learning how XSLT 2.0 does it too)

Comment: XPath (and that way XSLT) 2.0 has a tokenize function: http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-tokenize. With XSLT 1.0 you might also want to check whether your XSLT 1.0 processor supports the EXSLT tokenize function (http://www.exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/index.html).

Comment: With **EXSLT** you also have `split()` itself.

Comment: hey guys i've edited the question to reflect my problem

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for three different solutions :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I. XSLT 2.0 solution**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="vStr" select="'a,b,c,d,e'"/>

  <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($vStr, ',')">
   <option value="{.}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></option>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on ant XML document (not used), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<option value="a">a</option>
<option value="b">b</option>
<option value="c">c</option>
<option value="d">d</option>
<option value="e">e</option>
```

**Explanation**: Use of the standard XPath 2.0 function **[`tokenize()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-tokenize)**.

**II. XSLT 1.0: Using the [FXSL](http://fxsl.sf.net) 1.x `str-split-to-words` function/template**

This XSLT 1.0 transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
 exclude-result-prefixes="ext">
  <xsl:import href="strSplit-to-Words.xsl"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="vwordNodes">
        <xsl:call-template name="str-split-to-words">
          <xsl:with-param name="pStr" select="/"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="pDelimiters"
                          select="', '"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:apply-templates select=
       "ext:node-set($vwordNodes)/*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="word">
     <option value="{.}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></option>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<t>a,b,c d,e</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<option value="a">a</option>
<option value="b">b</option>
<option value="c">c</option>
<option value="d">d</option>
<option value="e">e</option>
```

**Do note** The `pDelimiters` parameter (as its name says) can hold more than one delimiting character -- in this case we use both `','` and `' '`.

**III. XSLT 1.0 solution using hand-written recursive named template**:

This transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="text()" name="tokenize">
  <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
  <xsl:param name="pDelim" select="','"/>

  <xsl:if test="string-length($pText) > 0">
    <xsl:variable name="vToken" select=
    "substring-before(concat($pText,','), ',')"/>

    <option value="{$vToken}">
      <xsl:value-of select="$vToken"/>
    </option>

    <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
     <xsl:with-param name="pText" select=
      "substring-after($pText,',')"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<t>a,b,c,d,e</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<option value="a">a</option>
<option value="b">b</option>
<option value="c">c</option>
<option value="d">d</option>
<option value="e">e</option>
```

**IV. Passing to the `tokenize` template in III above as a parameter a template/function to process each token**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:f="http://fxsl.sf.net" exclude-result-prefixes="f">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <f:processToken/>

 <xsl:variable name="vFunc" select=
  "document('')/*/f:processToken[1]"/>

 <xsl:template match="text()" name="tokenize">
  <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
  <xsl:param name="pDelim" select="','"/>
  <xsl:param name="pProcessFunc" select="$vFunc"/>

  <xsl:if test="string-length($pText) > 0">
    <xsl:variable name="vToken" select=
    "substring-before(concat($pText,','), ',')"/>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="$pProcessFunc">
     <xsl:with-param name="arg1" select="$vToken"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>

    <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
     <xsl:with-param name="pText" select=
      "substring-after($pText,',')"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="f:processToken">
  <xsl:param name="arg1"/>
    <option value="{$arg1}">
      <xsl:value-of select="$arg1"/>
    </option>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied to the same XML document as in III, the same, wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<option value="a">a</option>
<option value="b">b</option>
<option value="c">c</option>
<option value="d">d</option>
<option value="e">e</option>
```

**Now, if we substitute the last template with this one**:

```
 <xsl:template match="f:processToken">
  <xsl:param name="arg1"/>
    <p>
      <xsl:value-of select="$arg1"/>
    </p>
 </xsl:template>
```

**again the desired result is produced**:

```
<p>a</p>
<p>b</p>
<p>c</p>
<p>d</p>
<p>e</p>
```

Comment: this is cool, btw is there a way for us to write a custom `tokenize()` function/template in XSLT 1.0 or is it just not possible to do so ?

Comment: Yep, I am still completing my answer -- see the current update for a solution with the FXSL standard template function to use in this and many similar cases without the need to write recursive templates all over again. :)

Comment: @Pacerier: I have done the final update to my answer -- it now contains three solutions -- hopefully at least some of them will be useful to you? :)

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev . btw is there a way for us to make the function (third example) accept an arbitrary *template* (in this case our *template* is   `<option value="{$vToken}">
      <xsl:value-of select="$vToken"/>
    </option>`) as a parameter so basically we will have a *generic* function that can not only do `<option value="x">x</option>` but also fit any arbitrary requirements..

Comment: @Pacerier: See my edited result -- it now includes a complete solution to your latest requirement :)

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev uh.. actually i wanted a solution without additional dependencies that has accepts the template as a parameter.. but i guess i'm really asking for too much this time round lol

Comment: @Pacerier: What do you mean "without additional dependencies"? I have described in my last solution the most general way to implement Higher Order Functions (HOF) in XSLT, as done by FXSL.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev as in without having to use external libraries like FXSL (so just pure XSL 1.0 just like the third solution)

Comment: @Pacerier: You are missing the most important thing: FXSL is written in pure XSLT itself! So, using FXSL doesn't bring any additional dependencies. You can use FXSL with any XSLT processor. No dependencies.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev . i get ur point, its a bad choice of words on my part. when i said `without additional dependencies`, i actually meant something along the lines of: `without having to use FXSL`

Comment: @Pacerier: This is like saying you want to live without electricity and gas heating... Possible, heroic, ascetic, but nor clever.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev ok i had to admit XSLT 1.0 with no extensions is just impossible

Comment: @Pacerier: Yes, it is universally acknowledged that the `xxx:node-set()` extension function is needed in order to do meaningful XSLT 1.0 development. People use the EXSLT extension for this, because EXSLT is implemented by most XSLT 1.0 processors. Therefore, using `ext:nodeset()`, where the prefix `ext:` is bound to `http://exslt.org/common` isn't a significant hindrance of portability. Besides this extension function, it is an ERROR to call pure XSLT code "extensions". Anything written in pure XSLT, no matter by whom, is pure XSLT code -- not extensions.

Answer (score 0):

The answer you saw is only missing a ***delimiter*** parameter:

```
<xsl:template name="output-tokens">
    <xsl:param name="list" />
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" />
    <xsl:variable name="newlist">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($list, $delimiter)"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($list)" /></xsl:when>

            <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="concat(normalize-space($list), $delimiter)"/></xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="first" select="substring-before($newlist, $delimiter)" />
    <xsl:variable name="remaining" select="substring-after($newlist, $delimiter)" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$first" /> <!-- token -->
    <xsl:if test="$remaining">
        <xsl:call-template name="output-tokens">
            <xsl:with-param name="list" select="$remaining" />
            <xsl:with-param name="delimiter"><xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/></xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: sry if the first question wasn't clear.. i've updated it (since this answer isn't doing what i wanted..)