# What's the big deal with using the `&lt;` instead of simply `<` to do comparisons in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

Ok in XSLT i often see:

```xml
<xsl:if test="a &gt; b">
```

so what's the big deal with it?

I mean i changed it to `<xsl:if test="a > b">` and its working fine.. why not just use this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XSLT files are XML files also; The [XML Spec says not to use '<' and '&' literally except in certain contexts](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#syntax).  So this is a matter of keeping well formed XML within your XSLT file.

Comment: heys i've just read that link and it says they can be used within a processing instruction. i'm wondering if our code is `<xsl:if test="string-length($pText) > 0">` does the part `"string-length($pText) > 0"` qualify as a processing instruction?

Answer (score 3):

Nothing to do with XSLT, apart the fact that it's XML, and XML disallows `<` (but not `>`) in attribute values:

```
$ cat > a.xml
<elm a=">"/>
$ xmllint a.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<elm a="&gt;"/>
$ cat > b.xml
<elm b="<"/>
$ xmllint b.xml
b.xml:1: parser error : Unescaped '<' not allowed in attributes values
<elm b="<"/>
        ^
b.xml:1: parser error : attributes construct error
<elm b="<"/>
        ^
b.xml:1: parser error : Couldn't find end of Start Tag elm line 1
<elm b="<"/>
        ^
b.xml:1: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document
<elm b="<"/>
        ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the <> are tag delimiters - therefore we need to escape this as an entity & l t ; or  & # x 3 e ; as a sequence

Comment: living example which proves what you said is wrong: Go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282417/i-would-like-to-implement-a-split-function-template-which-takes-as-input-a-stri/6317062 and do a search for `<xsl:if test="string-length($pText) > 0">`

Answer (score 0):

> I mean i changed it to `<xsl:if
>   test="a < b">` and its working fine..
>   why not just use this?

**If this is really true, your so called "XSLT processor" wasn't one**. Any XSLT stylesheet must be a well-formed XML document. Any well-formed XML document cannot contain the character `"<"` inside an attribute value.

Therefore, please, correct the untrue statement in your question.