# Unescaped '<' not allowed in attributes values error in R

Tags: xml, r, parsing

I have a number of "raw" subject data in XML format that I need to read into a data table to process some summary statistics.  The program I used for testing gives me the following output (snippet of one event within the file):

```
    <Event>
      <Data name="Relation1" value="<"></Data>
      <Data name="Relation2" value="4    R"></Data>
      <Data name="Group" value="0"></Data>
      <Data name="CorrResult" value="S"></Data>
      <Data name="Response" value="S"></Data>
      <Data name="RT" value="787"></Data>
      <Data name="Result" value="C"></Data>
      <Data name="Gap" value="0"></Data>
      <Data name="IntraGap" value="0"></Data>
      <Data name="ISI" value="0"></Data>
    </Event>
```

The first data field "Relation1" will always have a value as either "<" or ">".  Is there a way I can ask R to recognize that as a data value and not the start of a new attribute value?  I've tried a number of things using the XML and XML2R packages and always end up with the error at the top of a long list of errors.

Comment: I thing it would be easier to do simple text parsing with eg. `stringr`.

Comment: I don't have a solution for you, but this post may be of interest: Apparently the problem is with the XML specification, not with R. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322126/whats-the-big-deal-with-using-the-lt-instead-of-simply-to-do-comparison

Comment: Thanks Maciej for pointing that out.  I have 120 events per subject so a little for-loop magic and I accomplish what I need.

Answer (score 6):

In XML < or & are strictly illegal to use as values. There are more which are not strictly illegal but are better avoided. Use an entity reference instead. So your XML file generates an error. The entity reference for < is `&lt;` and > is `&gt;`

If you can't change the output procedure, you can write a procedure to change the file in a text-based way; I mean, read the file line by line. If relation1 is detected, change the first < or > after that; after that it should work. I can't show you how this is done in R as I don't know the language.

I used the source below for reference.

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp

Answer (score 0):

I never did come back to this to post how I did it, so I apologize for that.  I ended up parsing it as a text file. It might not be the most elegant solution, but it gave me the results to finish my dissertation.

```
for(i in 1:length(filelist)) {
    #Parse raw data file
    xmlData <- readLines(filelist[i])
    tempTable <- data.frame(Event=1:64,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    temp <- read.table(text=as.character(xmlData[c(grep("Relation1",xmlData))]),sep="\"")
    tempTable[,"Relation1"] <- temp[-c(1,2,3,5)]
    tempTable[1,"SwTr"] = 0
    for(j in 2:64) { 
        if(tempTable[j,"Relation1"]==tempTable[j-1,"Relation1"])
            tempTable[j,"SwTr"] = 0 
        else 
            tempTable[j,"SwTr"] = 1 
    }
    temp <- read.table(text=as.character(xmlData[c(grep("RT",xmlData))]),sep="\"")
    tempTable[,"RT"] <- temp[-c(1,2,3,5)]
    temp <- read.table(text=as.character(xmlData[c(grep("\"Result\"",xmlData))]),sep="\"")
    tempTable[,"Result"] <- temp[-c(1,2,3,5)]
    tempLSW[i,"IDNum"] <- substr(filelist[i], start=10, stop=15)            #Get ID from filename
    swtRT <- sum(tempTable[tempTable$SwTr==1, "RT"])/sum(tempTable[,"SwTr"]==1) #Calc switch average
    nonSwt <- sum(tempTable[tempTable$SwTr==0, "RT"])/sum(tempTable[,"SwTr"]==0)    #Calc non-switch average
    tempLSW[i, "LSW.Cost"] <- round(swtRT-nonSwt, digits = 2)               #Set Switch cost in OSData
}
```